# Unicode code point limit

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

As explained [here](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen6), All unicode encodings end at largest code point `10FFFF` But I've heard differently that
they can go upto 6 bytes, is it true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UTF-8 underwent some changes during its life, and there are many specifications (most of which are outdated now) which standardized UTF-8. Most of the changes were introduced to help compatibility with UTF-16 and to allow for the ever-growing amount of codepoints.

To make the long story short, UTF-8 was originally specified to allow codepoints with up to 31 bits (or 6 bytes). But with [RFC3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), this was reduced to 4 bytes max. to be more compatible to UTF-16.

Wikipedia has some more [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The specification of the [Universal Character Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set) is closely linked to the history of Unicode and its transformation format (UTF).

Comment: @Ted: As I said, it all depends on what you actually claim UTF-8 to be, there are different (partly obsolete) standards. The most current one is RFC 3692. Also note that UTF is not UCS. UTF-8 just defines an encoding standard for the characters defined in UCS (hence ISO 10646-1)

Comment: @Holger: “The most current one is RFC 3692” -> RFC 3629, not 3692 (you were right with your first post).

Comment: @Hibou57: It... ehmm... was a test :) You are right of course.

Comment: The utf-8 mechanism allows really a maximum of a 8-byte sequence. Already a 7-byte sequence would have not a single bit as payload in the startbyte nore would have the 8-byte sequences startbyte have any payload bit. But the 7-byte sequence results in 6 x 6 = 36 payload bits of the following bytes and the 8-byte sequence results in even 7 x 6 = 42 bits of the following bytes. But due to the 0x10ffff unicode codepoint limit a maximum of a 4-byte sequence with utf-8 is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

See the answers to [Do UTF-8,UTF-16, and UTF-32 Unicode encodings differ in the number of characters they can store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130438/do-utf-8-utf-16-and-utf-32-unicode-encodings-differ-in-the-number-of-characters/)

UTF-8 and UTF-32 are theoretically capable of representing characters above U+10FFFF, but were artificially restricted to match UTF-16's capacity.

Comment: Right. The restrictions for utf-8 and utf-32 are however not only the limit of the highest codepoint but also to NOT encode surrogates and for utf-8, to use always the shortest sequence possible.

Answer (score 3):

The largest unicode codepoint and the encodings for unicode characters used, are two things. According to the standard, the highest codepoint really is 0x10ffff but herefore you'll need just 21 bits which fit easily into 4 bytes, even with 11 bits wasted!

I guess with your question about 6 bytes you mean a 6-byte utf-8 sequence, right? As others have answered already, using the utf-8 mechanism you could really deal with 6-byte sequences, you can even deal with 7-byte sequences and even with an 8-byte sequence. The 7-byte sequence gives you a range of just what the following bytes have to offer, 6 x 6 bits = 36 bits and a 8-byte sequence gives you 7 x 6 bits = 42 bits. You could deal with it but it is not allowed because unneeded, the highest codepoint is 0x10ffff.

It is also forbidden to use longer sequences than needed as Hibou57 has mentioned. With utf-8 one must always use the shortest sequence possible or the sequence will be treated as invalid! An ASCII character must be in a 7-bit singlebyte of course. The second thing is that the utf-8 4-byte sequence gives you 3 bits of payload in the startbyte and 18 bits of payload in the following bytes which are 21 bits and that matches to the calculation of surrogates when using the utf-16 encoding. The bias 0x10000 is subtracted from the codepoint and the remaining 20 bits go to the high- as well lo-surrogate payload area, each of 10 bits. The third and last thing is, that within utf-8 it is not allowed to encode hi- or -lo-surrogate values. Surrogates are not characters but containers for them, surrogates can only appear in utf-16, not in utf-8 or utf-32 encoded files.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, for some view of the UTF‑8 encoding, UTF‑8 may technically permit to encode code‑points beyond the forever‑fixed valid range upper‑limit; so one may encode a code‑point beyond that range, but it will not be a valid code‑point anywhere. On the other hand, you may encode a character with unneeded zeroed high‑order bits, ex. encoding an ASCII code‑point with multiple bits, like in `2#1100_0001#, 2#1000_0001#` (using Ada's notation), which would for the ASCII letter `A` UTF‑8 encoded with two bytes. But then, it may be rejected by some safety/security filters, at this use to be used for hacking and piracy. RFC 3629 has some explanation about it. One should just stick to encode valid code‑points (as defined by Unicode), the safe way (no extraneous bytes).