# Total number of UTF16 Characters

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, utf-16

Can you calculate that a UTF16 Encoding represents 1,112,064 numbers by permuations/commbinations?

Comment: Please expand: as it stands it doesn't make sense.

Comment: As for UTF-8, It is known to represent 2^31 possible characters. I was thinking if you apply the formula to calculate possible number of UTF-16 characters.

Comment: Would there have been 2^16 possibilities?

Comment: But UTF-8 does not represent 2^31 possible characters. 31 bits represents 2^31 possible characters, but UTF-8 does not cover all 31 bits, by specification (RFC 3629). To say that it does is wrong, it would not be UTF-8 if there were a character encoded using values outside the specified range.

Comment: Don’t confuse code points with characters. U+FFFF is not a character; neither is U+D800.  But both are code points. They’re just not valid for interchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UNICODE standard is section 3.9 says:

> Each encoding form maps the Unicode code points U+0000..U+D7FF and U+E000..U+10FFFF to unique code unit sequences.

Hence the number of code points ('characters') that can be represented by UTF-16 is

```
0xD7FF + 1 + (0x10FFFF - 0xE000) + 1 = 1 112 064
```

The UNICODE standard is generally 32-bit. However, specific encodings reserve smaller amount of bits to represent the most common characters impose specific limitations on the real number of characters they can legally represent. To allow for longer bit sequences that in turn allow describing code points longer that 8 (UTF-8) or 16 (UTF-16) bits special surrogate code points are defined.

Also, being able to *represent* a given code point in the given encoding doesn't mean it is valid — it has to be allocated and described by the UNICODE standard first. Therefore there's no mathematical formula which would yield the number of characters that can be represented and the number 1 112 064 doesn't necessarily mean there are 1M valid characters.

For a detailed discussion see [section 3.9](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/ch03.pdf#G7404) of the UNICODE standard.

Answer (score 4):

No. The number of characters represented by UTF-16 is only knowable by specification, not by mathematics. UTF-16 is a specific set of encoding rules laid out by people, not an intrinsic property of some formula.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280182/

It is almost as good as a specification, well, it combines some specifications.  I'll quote:

> UTF-16 is a variable-length code; its characters consume either 2 or 4 bytes. 2-byte values in the range 0xD800-0xDFFF are reserved for constructing 4-byte characters, and all 4-byte characters consist of two bytes in the range 0xD800-0xDBFF followed by 2 bytes in the range 0xDC00-0xDFFF. For this reason, Unicode does not assign any characters in the range U+D800-U+DFFF.
>
> Capacity of UTF-16: 1,112,064

Comment: Although surrogates are not characters, they are indeed code points. They simply aren’t valid for interchange because of the UTF-16 issue. But you have to be able to represent them internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent 1112064 scalar values in UTF-16 because there are 1112064 scalar values as defined by definition D76 in section 3.9 of the Standard, and because the UTF-16 encoding form (like all Unicode encoding forms) is a unique representation of all Unicode scalar values, as defined in definition D79.

> *D76* –   *Unicode scalar value:* Any Unicode code point except high-surrogate and low-surrogate code points.
>
> - As a result of this definition, the set of Unicode scalar values consists of the ranges 0 to D7FF and E000 to 10FFFF, inclusive.
>
> *D79* – A *Unicode encoding form* assigns each Unicode scalar value to a unique code unit sequence.

Of course, these numbers aren't completely arbitrary due to the mechanism of the surrogate pair encoding laid out in definition D91. Given the bit distribution in Table 3-5, there is just no way to encode a scalar value higher than 10FFFF.

Answer (score 1):

There are three kinds of UTF-16 code units:

- High surrogates (U+D800 to U+DBFF).  There are 1024 of these.
- Low surrogates (U+DC00 to U+DFFF).  There are 1024 of these.
- Directly representable characters in the BMP.  There are 65536-2*1024=63488 of these.

There are 1024×1024 = 1,048,576 that can be represented through surrogates (the "supplementary characters" U+10000 to U+10FFFF).  Add the 63,488 representable characters in the BMP and you get 1,112,064.