# Is there a Unicode character for the share icon?

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

I ve searched many times in google ,stackoverflow,html chars sites but I did not find what I need please help me about this:

I need this icon, representing a share action, as html unicode sequence:

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Question about the existence of characters are off-topic here. Besides, if you need something *for HTML*, then you are probably asking a wrong question. The existence of a character would not help you if e.g. it is so new that few if any fonts contain it.

Comment: What about this? ⚟

Comment: Note, this icon [is trademarked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share_icon) and had some legal issues. That's probably the reason why it was not added to unicode.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

---

As a minor aside / workaround for a bit of fun:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8rzgv/**

```
<span class="share">&lt;</span>

.share {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}
.share:before {
    content: ".";
    font-size: 2.2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2.5px;
    left: -4px;
}
.share:after {
    content: ":";
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    right: -7px;
}
```

Comment: so do you know any share icon chars in html ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Why don'y you look at the Wikipedia link and have a browse? `;-)`

Comment: I look but maybe I miss :( there are hundreds

Comment: `&#83;&#104;&#97;&#114;&#101;&#33;` (sorry, couldn't resist) `;)`

Comment: thanks for answer but as I said I cant use this my own site , I need just a chars like this: $ ...

Comment: There are not "hundreds" of Unicode characters -- that is just the list of Unicode blocks. Per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924105/how-many-characters-can-be-mapped-with-unicode), there are 109,384 code points "actually assigned in Unicode 6.0".

Comment: just like magic! haha :D

Answer (score 9):

Since that share symbol doesn't exist on unicode range `u0000-uFFFF`, you may use instead an iconic font and import that symbol. E.g., if you look at http://fontello.com/ and you search for "share" you will find a similar symbol under Entypo font

[image]

(with Entypo the unicode sequence is `\uE800`). These fonts are also in SVG format and the size/color/tickness of the symbols can be managed by CSS properties

Comment: thanks for answer, actually I need it with unicode chars if eists :( because I copy it to tittle of my android app

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar don't worry, I don't care of downvotes. I just hope it can be useful to you or to other people reading at this question.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know it doesn't exists, and even if so, there is a very hight chance (like 99%) that the browser will not display it correctly. Try to use the brail coding, in particular this one is very similar to your needs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%A0%AA