# how many icons can I put in one icon font file?

Tags: icons

I would like to know how many Icons can I put in one icon font?

what is the best method to have the biggest amount of icons in one icon font file?

Answer (score 1):

Icon fonts define glyphs for Unicode code points, and therefore the theoretical limit is around 1 million icons, because that is the [number of code points that can be encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924105/how-many-characters-can-be-mapped-with-unicode).

Font formats may be limited to a certain number of symbols however. But even 1000 icons in a single font, which every format should support, are way too many for real world web applications because of the size and performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

So far FontAwesome has managed to squeeze 439 icons in a font. I guess when you run out of characters you can always make another font file and add that to your page as well.