# How to use the regular expression to transform the <U+5C16> into \u5c16?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am doing a sentiment analysis project and firstly, I need to clean the text data. Some text contains Chinese, Tagalog and what I am doing now is trying to translate them to English. But until now, all the Chinese characters in this datafile have some Unicode representation like:

```
<U+5C16>
```

which could not be coped with using the Python Encoding&Decoding path. So I want to transform this kind of pattern to:

```
\u5c16
```

Then I think we could use the following code to get the Chinese characters I want:

```
text.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode_escape')
```

So the question now is how to use the regex to transform `<U+5C16>` into`\u5c16`?

Thank you very much!

---

Update: I think the most difficult thing here is that I need to let the `5c16` part in `\u5c16` be equivalent to the lowercase of the `5C16` in `<U+5C16>`. And in my social media dataset, what I see most is the text data like the following:

`<U+5C16><U+6C99><U+5480><U+9418><U+6A13>`

If I could transform the above text to `'\u5c16\u6c99\u5480\u9418\u6a13'` and print it in Python, I could get what I really want:

```
尖沙咀鐘樓
```

But how could I do this? Any insights and hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Not quite get what do you mean by "Note the c in \u5c16 could also be u". 5c16 is a hexadecimal number and there can't be u in it.

Comment: @montonero Oh, I have edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: Are you _sure_ your file is Ascii with codes like this, or could this be how your editor or pager is showing real unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required regex is something like this:

find: `r'<U\+([A-Fa-f0-9]+?)>'`

replace with: `r'\u\1'`

To turn the resulting string to unicode make `s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')`

Example:

```
re.sub(r'<U\+([A-Fa-f0-9]+?)>',r'\u\1',s).encode().decode('unicode-escape')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your answer but it does not seem to work 

Comment: Currently, I could transform the '<U+5C16><U+6C99><U+5480><U+9418><U+6A13>' into '\\u5c16\\u6c99\\u5480\\u9418\\u6a13' by using the following code:



```Python

string = '<U+5C16><U+6C99><U+5480><U+9418><U+6A13>' 
result1 = re.sub('\<u\+', backslash+'u', string.lower())
result2 = re.sub('\>', '', result1)
result2
```

But how to get \u5c16\u6c99\u5480\u9418\u6a13 

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example how to turn replaced string to unicode characters.

Comment: The quantifier `+?` will always match exactly once :-)

Comment: @alexis It would. If it wasn't followed by any other character.

Comment: oh ok, I see. You were right, I missed that the `>` is in the regex. (But what's the point of the `?` anyway? There's only one way to match.)

Comment: @alexis Agree, ? is an overkill and is more a safe measure than a necessity in this case. But it does not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is exactly as you describe, here's how to convert it:

```
text = "text with <U+5C16> and so on"
ready = re.sub(r"<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4})>", r"\u\1", text)
go = re.sub(r"<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4})>", r"\u\1", text)    # BMP: 4 hex digits
go = re.sub(r"<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{5})>", r"\U000\1", go)   # SMP: 5 -> 8 hex digits
print(go.encode("ascii").decode('unicode_escape'))
```

(The line marked "SMP" is only needed if you have characters outside the "basic multilingual plane".)

Output: `text with 尖 and so on`

Comment: Unfortunately {4} is not a valid quantifier since Unicode character codes aren't bound to 16 bits.

Comment: If they are wider, you can't trivially convert them to `\uNNNN` form. If the OP wants to support the SMP as well, a second regex can convert 5-digit sequences to `r"\U000\1"`, (Anyway, `{4}` is a perfectly _valid_ quantifier; it just won't match every valid unicode escape. :-))

Comment: Python doesn't complain against `\uNNNNN` so {4} isn't quite correct.

Comment: Of course it doesn't complain; but the fifth digit is not read as part of the codepoint. You'll end up with `{16-bit codepoint}N`. Read the docs.

Comment: Anyway I did add handling for SMP characters, as you suggested. (But correctly ;-))

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415935/does-unicode-have-a-defined-maximum-number-of-code-points `The maximum valid code point in Unicode is U+10FFFF` so we could go even further and use \U which support 8 hex chars

Comment: Technically yes, but the entire range above `U+F0000` is in the private use area. So my regex is correct for any real Unicode text. (See ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Blocks.txt). And you have to pad, because `\U` must be followed by exactly 8 digits.