# What's the maximum number of code points for a UTF-8 encoded displayed character?

Tags: utf-8

We were attempting to insert emojis into our database, but were encountering weird behavior. It turns out this has to do with utf-8 encoding.  would work fine, but  would not. This is when we learned about utf-8 code points.  is a single code point long, but  is 2: consisting of Hot Pepper (U+1F336) and Variation Selector-16 (U+FE0F).

After learning of this, we increased the database storage width to 2, which fixed the problem for , but we found a new problem. Keycap emojis (1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣) are 3 characters: One (U+31), Variation Selector-16 (U+FE0F), and Combining Enclosing Keycap (U+20E3).

"Fine," we said, "Increase it to 4." Then ‍♂️ came in with 5 code points: Face Palm (U+1F926), Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick Type-3 (U+1F3FC), Zero Width Joiner (U+200D), Male Sign (U+2642), and Variation Selector-16 (U+FE0F). We tried a lot more and found England's flag  to be made of 7 code points:

- U+1F3F4: Waving Black Flag
- U+E0067: Tag Latin Small Letter G
- U+E0062: Tag Latin Small Letter B
- U+E0065: Tag Latin Small Letter E
- U+E006E: Tag Latin Small Letter N
- U+E0067: Tag Latin Small Letter G
- U+E007F: Cancel Tag

So the question is, what's the greatest number of codepoints that a displayed unicode character can use? Are there any examples of emojis (or other utf-8 characters) with higher than 7 code points?

This question is similar to, but different from, the question [What is the maximum number of bytes for a UTF-8 encoded character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9533258/1248889). That asks for a single UTF-8 codepoint, what's the maximum number of bytes? (Spoiler: 4). This question shares a similar title to [Does Unicode have a defined maximum number of code points?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27415935/1248889), but that's asking how many different code-points exist. Not how many can be used in a row to make up a single character displayed on the screen.

Comment: Technically there's no limit to emoji sequences. Anyone _could_ make up new ever longer sequences and create a font that supports them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't gotten to the long ones yet....

There are two short answers for your question:

- The technically correct, but useless answer: There is no limit.
- The current recommended limit that probably won't be expanded on too soon: 10. For example, the kissing emojis with two skin tones (for example, ‍❤️‍‍). That's 36 bytes in UTF-8 BTW.

These are ZWJ (Zero Width Joiner) sequences, and are generally the longest emoji sequences in the recommendation. You can get the currently recommended list in [emoji-zwj-sequences](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/latest/emoji-zwj-sequences.txt).

The longest sequence that I've seen discussed, but is not part of the recommendation, is 11 for a skin tone modified family sequence (for example, woman-medium-zwj-woman-dark-zwj-girl-light-zwj-girl-medium). This sequence would almost certainly crush Unicode (supporting it would add over 4000 new glyphs), so it's unlikely to ever be in the recommendation.

But just because it's not recommended does not mean it's not legal. I can combine an arbitrarily large number of people together into a family sequence, attaching gender, hair color, and skin color to each, and it's a legal sequence and will render as a single "character." For example, this is the family emoji with skin-tone modifiers discussed above: ‍‍‍ It renders as four people, but if your text engine works correctly, you will find it selects as a single "character" because it is. There just isn't a special glyph for it in any common font.

I can also add other modifiers without limit, and you can add them to arbitrary characters (not just emoji). For all the gory details see [UTS #51: Unicode Emoji](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51).

And then you opened up the further question of "or other utf-8 characters." That's really about combining characters, and that introduces:

[ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Unicode puts no limit on the number of combining characters that can be attached to a single "starter" character.

However, Unicode does define a [Stream-Safe Text Format](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Stream_Safe_Text_Format), which puts a limit of 30 combining characters per "chunk." (It does actually allow additional combining characters by interposing a COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER, but these are normalized separately.) A complete chunk will not contain more than 32 characters total, and will not require more than 128 bytes to encode in UTF-8.

As the spec notes, "the value of 30 is chosen to be significantly beyond what is required for any linguistic or technical usage." The largest I've heard of is 8 combining characters in the Tibetan [HAKṢHMALAWARAYAṀ](https://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2010-m01/0185.html) (ཧྐྵྨླྺྼྻྂ). That's one character. (That said, while I've seen this particular example thrown around a lot, I've never seen anyone describe how it is used by Tibetans, so I cannot confirm that this is actually a real character.)

Comment: Just to add: the answer may assume a canonical version. As Unicode standard tell us: some inputs (especially direct from keyboard) may have extra codepoints which are not useful (but very long sequence). In any case I assume you will transform any string to a valid canonical form, so the answer is correct (just with a caveat) (so extra warning about invalid UTF-8 sequences: invalid bytes, overlong sequences, surrogates codes, etc.)

Comment: Amazing. Encoding is so much more complex than I could imagine. Thank you for the very detailed response. The zalgo reference is very nostalgic!