# Nested for-loops and dictionaries in finding value occurrence in string

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been tasked with creating a dictionary whose keys are elements found in a string and whose values count the number of occurrences per value.

Ex.

```
"abracadabra" → {'r': 2, 'd': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 5}
```

I have the for-loop logic behind it here:

```
xs = "hshhsf"
xsUnique = "".join(set(xs))

occurrences = []
freq = []

counter = 0

for i in range(len(xsUnique)):
    for x in range(len(xs)):
        if xsUnique[i] == xs[x]:
            occurrences.append(xs[x])
            counter += 1
    freq.append(counter)
    freq.append(xsUnique[i])
counter = 0
```

This does exactly what I want it to do, except with lists instead of dictionaries. How can I make it so `counter` becomes a value, and `xsUnique[i]` becomes a key in a new dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *easiest* way is to use a Counter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("abracadabra")
Counter({'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
```

If you can't use a Python library, you can use [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default value of `0` to make your own counter:

```
s="abracadabra"
count={}
for c in s:
    count[c] = count.get(c, 0)+1

>>> count
{'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Or, you can use [dict.fromkeys()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) to set all the values in a counter to zero and then use that:

```
>>> counter={}.fromkeys(s, 0)
>>> counter
{'a': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0}
>>> for c in s:
...    counter[c]+=1
... 
>>> counter
{'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

If you truly want the *least Pythonic*, i.e., what you might do in C, you would maybe do:

1. create a list for all possible ascii values set to `0`
2. loop over the string and count characters that are present
3. Print non zero values

Example:

```
ascii_counts=[0]*255
s="abracadabra"

for c in s:
    ascii_counts[ord(c)]+=1

for i, e in enumerate(ascii_counts):
    if e:
        print chr(i), e
```

Prints:

```
a 5
b 2
c 1
d 1
r 2
```

That does not scale to use with Unicode, however, since you would need [more than 1 million](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924105/how-many-characters-can-be-mapped-with-unicode) list entries...

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! I can't use any Python libraries for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` function to convert your list to dictionary :

```
>>> dict(zip(freq[1::2],freq[0::2]))
{'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}
```

But as more pythonic and pretty optimized way I suggest to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("hshhsf")
Counter({'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1})
```

And as you said you don't want to import any module you can use a dictionary using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method and a simple loop:

```
>>> d={}
>>> for i in xs:
...    d[i]=d.setdefault(i,0)+1
... 
>>> d
{'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}
```

Comment: I guess I would be looking for the least pythonic way to do it, as I'm in essence learning how to make a Counter function.  I'm new to this sort of stuff, so I have yet to play around with it's potential.

Comment: @ChrisAngj If you want to use this problem for practice and learning its OK but in otherwise  the right way is using `collections.Counter`. you can also use a dictionary to get the desire result directly!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing theres a `learning` reason as to why your using two forloops?
Anyway heres a few different solutions:

```
# Method 1
xs = 'hshhsf'
xsUnique = ''.join(set(xs))

freq1 = {}
for i in range(len(xsUnique)):
    for x in range(len(xs)):
        if xsUnique[i] == xs[x]:
            if xs[x] in freq1:
                freq1[xs[x]] += 1
            else:
                freq1[xs[x]] = 1 # Introduce a new key, value pair

# Method 2
# Or use a defaultdict that auto initialize new values in a dictionary
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

from collections import defaultdict

freq2 = defaultdict(int) # new values initialize to 0
for i in range(len(xsUnique)):
    for x in range(len(xs)):
        if xsUnique[i] == xs[x]:
            # no need to check if xs[x] is in the dict because 
            # defaultdict(int) will set any new key to zero, then
            # preforms it's operation.
            freq2[xs[x]] += 1


# I don't understand why your using 2 forloops though

# Method 3
string = 'hshhsf' # the variable name `xs` confuses me, sorry

freq3 = defaultdict(int)
for char in string:
    freq3[char] += 1

# Method 4
freq4 = {}
for char in string:
    if char in freq4:
        freq4[char] += 1
    else:
        freq4[char] = 1



print 'freq1: %r\n' % freq1
print 'freq2: %r\n' % freq2
print 'freq3: %r\n' % freq3
print 'freq4: %r\n' % freq4

print '\nDo all the dictionaries equal each other as they stand?'
print 'Answer: %r\n\n'  % (freq1 == freq2 and freq1 == freq3 and freq1 == freq4)

# convert the defaultdict's to a dict for consistency
freq2 = dict(freq2)
freq3 = dict(freq3)

print 'freq1: %r' % freq2
print 'freq2: %r' % freq2
print 'freq3: %r' % freq3
print 'freq4: %r' % freq4
```

### Output

```
freq1: {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}
freq2: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1})
freq3: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1})
freq4: {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}

Do all the dictionaries equal each other as they stand?
Answer: True


freq1: {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}
freq2: {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}
freq3: {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}
freq4: {'h': 3, 's': 2, 'f': 1}
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Or like dawg stated, use Counter from the collections standard library

counter docs

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

defaultdict docs

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

collections library docs

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: I'm using two for loops because it was how I taught myself to do it.  It's always cool to learn a shorter, more efficient, way.  Thanks!

Comment: That explains it. There are many short hand ways to solve problems regarding structured data in python. Look into list and dictionary comprehensions