# Allocation of size for a unicode character array

Tags: java, arrays, unicode, ascii

Depending on whether we want ASCII characters array or extended ASCII characters array, we generally either allocate a size of 128 or 256 for an ASCII character array that needs to hold all ASCII characters(I am taking a reference of Java arrays)

Let's say we want to do the same for a unicode character array, what size do we need to allocate for that array ?

Comment: Can you add an example of code you are referring to when talking about allocation?

Comment: `Character.MAX_VALUE + 1` for UTF-16. `Character.MAX_CODE_POINT + 1` for UTF-32.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924105/how-many-characters-can-be-mapped-with-unicode) should answer your question

Comment: What is an “ASCII character array”?  All char values in Java are UTF-16 code units.